# In Scrabble, can a normal play be scoreless?

Tags: scrabble

Scrabble rules say thay after at least six consecutive scoreless turns the game ends.

> Under North American tournament rules, the game ends when... at
>   least six successive scoreless turns have occurred...

It is also pretty clear for me that in absolute majority of cases a scoreless turn arises from either: 1) passing; 2) exchanging tiles; 3) losing a challenge.

But can a normal turn be scoreless? Imagine that a player laid something on the board, so he/she definitely played but scored nothing. Maybe it's extremely rare, but it is a possible event, isn't it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are two blank tiles which score zero. So if you played a two letter word using a second blank tile connecting to a blank tile, then your turn would score zero even though you played a word.

Also,  as Nathan has pointed out in the comments, you could play a two letter word with two blank tiles on the first turn.

Comment: Is it legal to play a single blank tile on the first turn?

Comment: @anomaly: No. Words must be 2 or more letters.

Comment: You could start off with the two blank tiles on the first turn :P